# Fetch data from django backend having parts of dynamic URL private

Tags: javascript, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

Let's say I am developing a django REST api that is secured via token and basic authentication. The idea is to list juices. So I am having an URL that lists all juices from specific brands.

So I got a dynamic URL like: `path("juices/<str:name_brand>/" ...)`

What I want to do now is to show all juices of the brand coca-cola in my frontend where no authentication is required. So all visitors should see the list of juices from coca-cola.

I need to use JS fetch since it has to be asynch. Thus my code is something like:

```
async function get_juices() {
  let juices = await fetch(
    `${hostname}/api/v1/juices/coca-cola/
  )
  result = await juices.json();
  return juices;
}
```

My backend is a simple ListView that dynamically filters by brand.

But my problem now is that the API is private and I can't use my credentials in my frontend for obvious security reasons. Because any user could just read the frontend code and use my credentials to access the juices of other brands too.

I was reading now in some posts that it is possible to have a proxy server which only accepts requests from a specific client and reroutes the request with credentials that are being saved on the proxy server. But I have no idea how to implement this with my django app.

I was wondering if there might be a simpler, quicker solution to access some dynamic URLs in public mode and others that are private?

Or any hints how I could implement a reverse proxy to achieve what I need?

Thanks very much in advance

EDIT:

My view:

```
class JuicesList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **url_params):
        name_brand = url_params.get("name_brand", None)
        result = Juices.objects.filter(name_brand=name_brand)
        return Response(result)
```

The default permission classes are "SessionAuthentication" and "TokenAuthentication"

Comment: You want to filter / show objects as per the user that makes the request yes? You can do that using permissions in DRF. Please show your view.

Comment: Well I want my own website to be able to get all juices from `/api/v1/juices/coca-cola/` when not being authenticated, but I want all other URLs to be private (`/api/v1/juices/pepsi/` should be private)

Comment: Or rephrased: I want to show for all visitors the data of `/api/v1/juices/coca-cola/`. But I want only authenticated staff users to be able to access `/api/v1/juices/pepsi/`

Comment: And finally let me add: I want no one to open the developer tools, read the request, adjust it and get other data which they are not allowed to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple if-else in your view and return an appropriate response with respect to the user and the brand name:

```
from rest_framework import status


class JuicesList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **url_params):
        name_brand = url_params.get("name_brand", None)
        if not request.user.is_staff and name_brand != 'coca-cola':
            return Response({'Error': 'Permission denied'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        result = Juices.objects.filter(name_brand=name_brand)
        return Response(result) # This not look correct? You haven't serialized the queryset?
```

Moving further, this type of permissions are a bit manual and not very DRY (do not repeat yourself), hence you can use [permissions DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/):

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class JuicesPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_staff or view.kwargs.get("name_brand", None) == 'coca-cola'


class JuicesList(APIView):

    permission_classes = [JuicesPermission]

    def get(self, request, **url_params):
        name_brand = url_params.get("name_brand", None)
        result = Juices.objects.filter(name_brand=name_brand)
        return Response(result)
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution and saves me quite some hussle. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. Short follow up question: Imagine I'd have to do this with many URLs and also with many different parameters. Is there a way to tell django to only allow requests from a certain host for specific dynamic URLs?

Comment: @shadow yes, should be possible, you would simply need to get the host name from the respective http header inside [`request.META` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! And I assume that would not pose major security risks doing handling this with permissions and getting the http-host?

Comment: @shadow I am personally not experienced in security, there may be some issues, you would need to consult some expert in that domain.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that :) Thank you again, that helped me very much